# Node-Sass Bourbon Gulp error import

Tags: sass, gulp, bourbon

I'm having trouble importing Bourbon into my scss using npm. I've installed both Sass and Bourbon using npm.

my import reads like this:

```
@import "../../node_modules/node-bourbon/node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
```

and this is the my gulp task for scss files:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
return gulp.src(assetsDev + 'scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss([precss, autoprefixer, cssnano]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(ext_replace('.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(assetsProd + 'css/'));
});
```

after saving the import path for the first time, this is the error I get:

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/yosemetie/Documents/github/udemey-ng2/directives-part1/node_modules/node-bourbon/node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon.css'
>       at Error (native)

One other thing to note is that when I comment out a class like this in my scss file:

```
//h1{
//  color: #4c4c4c;
//}
```

gulp throws an error -

> /app.scss:10:1: Unknown word
>   //  color: #4c4c4c;
>   //}

however if I write it like this:

```
h1{
  //color: #4c4c4c;
}
```

No error gets thrown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance - still new to gulp here.

Comment: I ended up having to use gulp-sass, gulp-autoprefixer instead and that seemed to work!